# Calculate average speed from gps based on an equation

Tags: java, android

I am trying to calculate the average battery length in minutes of a motor using the following equation: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7A6bu.jpg

I get the average speed by using the following code:

```
for (Location location : locationResult.getLocations()) {
    int speed = (int) (location.getSpeed() * 2.2369);
    float addedSpeed = avgMPH + speed;
    avgMPH = addedSpeed / 2;
    float math1 = 45 / avgMPH;
    batteryView.setText("Battery: " + String.valueOf(math1 * 60) + " Minutes Remaining");
    }
```

The issue is that every time the location loops it doubles my battery life each loop even though it is still at 1 miles per hour. it should not loop like this, help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: this formula is strange, resulting "battery length" will be in `hour*min`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are calculating average speed wrong. 
You should calculate like this:

```
 float addedSpeed = avgMPH * numSamples + speed;
 avgMPH = addedSpeed / (numSamples + 1);
 numSamples = numSamples + 1;
```

Not like this:

```
float addedSpeed = avgMPH + speed;
avgMPH = addedSpeed / 2;
```

For example, think you went 1 mph for 10 hours and 100 mph for a hour.
Former will give you average 10 mph which is correct and latter will give you average 55.5 mph which is wrong.